# Is there any generally useful magic that can be done if all it could do was violate the Third Law of Thermodynamics?

Tags: magic, physics

Is there any generally useful magic that can be done if all it could do was violate the [Third Law of Thermodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_law_of_thermodynamics)?

The Third Law of Thermodynamics just seems to relate to [absolute zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_zero)? And it says that:

> It is impossible for any process, no matter how idealized, to reduce the entropy of a system to its absolute-zero value in a finite number of operations.
>
> Physically, the Nernst–Simon statement implies that it is impossible for any procedure to bring a system to the absolute zero of temperature in a finite number of steps.[3]

Comment: What do you consider to be "generally useful"?

Comment: Interestingly enough, a lot of sci-fi technology (or "magic" with some pseudo-scientific basis) is based around violating (at least) this law of thermodynamics, **or** (and this is not the same thing) assuming they can somehow violate the third law would provide a decent explanation for how they can do what they do. But the law itself isn't mentioned in a lot of fiction outside of very "hard" sci-fi, because people balk at these tersely stated scientific statements.

Comment: @Frostfyre - I guess some power that most people would want, if they had that magic, but also not something that seems non-useful on first glance, like the power to change the color of any object to green.

Comment: If **all it could do** was violate the third law? Instant super-conductor spell maybe?

Comment: Greg Bear's novella *Heads* posits that at T=0, quantum field distributions go flat, space-time undergoes a phase change not seen since the Big Bang, information flows in funny ways, and things get hideously weird.

Comment: My gut feeling is that reaching 0K necessarily comes with reaching the speed of light and solving the halting problem, both of which can be considered useful (although Charles Stross would have second thoughts). But it's only a gut feeling ;-).

Comment: Once you poke a hole in any part of thermodynamics I imagine there is a path to violating any other parts you might want. The explanation may be circuitous (that is, "boring to your audience"), but this should generally be true.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

**Violating any of the laws of thermodynamics would be very useful.**

If you can violate the third law then you can get a substance to reach (or since it's magic, go below) absolute zero.

The laws are occasionally humorously defined like this:

[image]

[The efficiency of a heat engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_Engine#Efficiency) follows this formula from Carnot:

$$\eta = 1 - {{T_C}\over{T_H}} $$

If you can get $T_C$ to zero, the efficiency is unity. If you can get it lower than zero, efficiency is greater than unity. That means if you can actually reach zero, you can get 100% efficiency. If you can magic something to be below absolute zero, you can get more than 100% efficiency. This is known as free energy.

In general, free energy is considered useful.

Comment: "In general, free energy is considered useful."

Comment: +1 just for the "you can't win, you can only draw" reference, I always loved that. I know we're talking "magic" so hand waving is more or less a given, but even so it seems like T < 0 should have no meaning, since atoms would have to be moving "less" than not at all. Also, to get there you have to break the laws of Quantum Mechanics as well as thermodynamics, otherwise you're not allowed to know where your extremely cold thing is, which could get messy.

Comment: If we can live in a world where negative interest rates are a thing, I can kind of get my head around negative motion, in a hand-wavy, magic-y way...

Comment: This would be *particularly* useful in a world like that of Eragon, where "magic" is really the manipulation of energy of various descriptions. Being able to break the laws of thermodynamics in this way to gain "free energy" would potentially make someone infinitely powerful (or if there was still a limit to the amount of free energy they made, or the rate at which they made it, would make them proportionately more powerful)

Comment: @JosephRogers Actually, supposedly [negative absolute temperature is at least a theoretical possibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_temperature). Of course, one can still argue about what this really *means*...

Comment: @MichaelKjörling fascinating! As if thermodynamics wasn't hard enough!

Comment: I always heard the three laws as, "1. You can't win, 2. You can't break even, 3. You can't stop playing the game."

Comment: Reaching 0 would violate the law, and it would not provide free energy, only perfect efficiency (for as long as the cold reservoir lasted). Achieving negative temperatures... it's not clear what that means (nor, strictly speaking, whether it would violate the law), but it might be a heat sink that would run a heat engine at >100% efficiency, but again only until the heat destroyed the reservoir. It would be a very expensive battery, not a world-changer.

Comment: @Beta Yes, you've summarized my answer well enough. Except for the final point, this would definitely change the world.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling not just a theoretical possibility - it's demonstrated in every laser, for example. But the third law doesn't apply in that case, since the third law is only for certain types of matter. (Either perfect crystals or solids and liquids, depending on how its stated.) The degrees of freedom that have negative temperatures in a laser are neither of those things, so it's OK. But it does suggest that the third law is nowhere near as fundamental as the other two.

Comment: I've always heard: You can't win, you can't draw, you can't even lose gracefully.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I understand, you'll also get rid of the quantum [uncertainty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle): since a particles do not move, you can know both their momentum (zero) and their position. There already are some [workarounds](http://www.zmescience.com/science/physics/particle-momentum-position-measurement-54354/) that reduce the uncertainty, and they are linked to the possibility of the quantum computing - so, I guess your magic could be used in quantum computer.

By the way, getting the system lower than zero does not require magic:
http://www.quantum-munich.de/research/negative-absolute-temperature/

Comment: If you had the rule of uncertainty broken, you could teleport, create matter(/energy) from nothing and turn matter(/energy) to nothing.